# USB stick detected but no files are showing up

Tags: server, usb, 22.04

I'm using ubuntu server and I'm trying to transfer files over usb but I'm having a weird problem. The usb stick is detected but no files are showing up. For example, I plugin the usb stick, I navigate to /media, I run ls, and nothing shows' up. I've even tried changing dirs to one that's on the usb stick and it just says that it doesn't exist.

things I've tried:

- using a different os
- using a different port

Comment: Keep an eye on the terminal command `sudo journalctl  --follow` as you plug in the USB drive. What system was it working on? How was it unmounted? After it's plugged in, `df -m | grep -v loop` and `sudo lsblk -f` and `ls -l /media/$USER` will help you find it.

Comment: it showed up but gave this as soon as i plugged it in `sda1: Process '/usr/bin/unshare -m /usr/bin/snap auto-import --mount=/dev/sda1' failed with exit code 1.`

Comment: You've provided no specific product/release details (is this a Ubuntu Core server? or Ubuntu Server? what release of *unstated* server product?), nor if you actually mounted the device/partition, nor what file-system was utilized on it?.

Comment: You've provided no specific product/release details (is this a Ubuntu Core server? or Ubuntu Server? what release of *unstated* server product?), nor if you actually mounted the device/partition, nor what file-system was utilized on it?.

Comment: i am on ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].

Comment: @gulverc I have the same problem.  An lsb_release -a says "Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS" - for me this is a straight GUI install as I use it as a desktop.

Comment: Does the same problem occur if you try it with a different USB stick?

Comment: Every reason that a USB will not boot: https://askubuntu.com/q/1190764/43926